# Under what option should i upload a revised main document when using manuscriptcentral?

Tags: peer-review

**[please edit this question or propose a better title, English is not my native language]**

Recently my paper was accepted with major revisions in a journal using  [mc.manuscriptcentral](https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com) in its submission process.

I revised my paper and edited the main document, and now i want to upload it now, but there is still Authors bio in that document, so under what should i upload it, the website proposes the following choice ?
[image]

Comment: Looks like it should be 'main document - with author details'?

Comment: Don't worry about it, when you get it wrong someone will tell you what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be "Main document". The reason it says "- with author details" is probably because, as you said, your article has already been accepted. So, the label "Main document - with author details" probably means that you should now add your author information; you should no longer hide it as you were probably required to do in the double-blind peer review stage.

I'm not absolutely certain, but based on the details you provided, that seems to be the most likely option.